# datetimepicker not getting removed on change of select drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

I am trying the below code to add and remove a datetimepicker on change of event.  It's getting applied on the change event of a `select` but not getting removed in the `else` condition. Could anyone help on this?

```js
function showoption(obj) {
  if (obj.value == "date") {
    $('#txtval').datetimepicker({
      weekStart: 1,
      todayBtn: 1,
      autoclose: 1,
      todayHighlight: 1,
      startView: 2,
      forceParse: 0,
      showMeridian: 1,
      pickerPosition: "bottom-left",
      startDate: new Date()
    });
  } else {
    $('#txtval').datetimepicker("destroy");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="datatype" id="datatype" onchange="return showoption(this)">
  <option value="int">Int</option>
  <option value="float">Float</option>
  <option value="date">Date</option>
</select><br />
<input type="text" name="txtval" id="txtval" />
```

Comment: Which datetimepicker library are you using?

Comment: you want date time picker or only date picker ?

Comment: @vinit Ignore my edit on your answer.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan, while checking the js there is no version mentioned inside file but we have implemented it 2 years back.While checking latest version it seems that we have add moment.js supporting js also and it doesn't support existing params which we are currently passing.. please correct if i am wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If destroy isn't working then I'd suggest inspecting the `$('#txtval')` element before and after the datetimepicker is initialized.

You could then manually remove any classes that have been added:

```
$('#txtval').removeClass('datetimepickerclass');
```

Finally you could then unbind all the events that were added by the plugin

```
$('#txtval').off(); //or .unbind() depending on jQuery version
```

Comment: off() method works to remove datetimepicker but when i again change the date datatype from select drop down then it doesn't show the datetimepicker once again.also while inspecting there is no extra class gets added when datetimepicker gets applied.

Comment: Are you re-initializing your datetimepicker when you change the date datatype?

Comment: The question was about 'removing datetimepicker' so please accept the answer if it has solved your initial problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement this one for your datetimepicker. It works fine for my datepicker.

```js
function showoption(obj) {
  if (obj.value == "date") {
    $('#txtval').datepicker({
      weekStart: 1,
      todayBtn: 1,
      autoclose: 1,
      todayHighlight: 1,
      startView: 2,
      forceParse: 0,
      showMeridian: 1,
      pickerPosition: "bottom-left",
      startDate: new Date()
    });
  } else {
    $('#txtval').datepicker("destroy");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<select name="datatype" id="datatype" onchange="return showoption(this)">
  <option value="int">Int</option>
  <option value="float">Float</option>
  <option value="date">Date</option>
</select><br />
<input type="text" name="txtval" id="txtval" />
```

Comment: Ye and it would probably have worked if all the libraries where correctly included.

Comment: He says it's getting 'applied' so I guess we can assume all the necessary scripts are included

Comment: well since mine works with all libraries I would like to see an edit of prove, so I can check whether I'm wrong or not. If he includes all and it doesn't work I'm willing to search for an other explanation.

Comment: @mrdeadsven it seems i am using old version which doesn't support destroy method.even i have searched for this keyword but didn't found any occurrence.

Comment: @vinitagrawal oke, then you can always make it and input field again. In the else statement you can use following code: $('#txtval').attr({ type: 'text', id: 'txtval', name: 'txtval'}); . This will make it and input field again.

Comment: @mrdeadsven tried your solution but the datetimepicker not getting unbind.now i dropped the datetimepicker idea and shifted to datepicker